# More Robust code for HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I wrote a great little piece of code (*really* trying not to be cocky with that) implementing a nice background changing across three types of filtering.  Here's the html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<!-- Head -->
<head>
    <title>html_three_vertical_div_backgrounds</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />   

    <!-- Area for Additional Links -->
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='html_three_vertical_div_backgrounds.css' />
</head>

<!-- Body -->
<body>
    <div id='left'></div>
    <div id='middle'></div>
    <div id='right'></div>
</body>
```

... and the CSS:

```
#left {
/* Set the float (left) */
float: left;
/* Set the width */
width: 33%;
/* Set the height */
height: 100vh;
/* Filter */
-webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
/* We actually have to post the image all three times */
background-image: url("http://images2.fanpop.com/image/photos/9800000/Great-Mountains-mountains-and-waterfalls-9842020-1920-1440.jpg");
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
}

#middle {
float: left;
width: 34%;
height: 100vh;
-webkit-filter: sepia(1);
background-image: url("http://images2.fanpop.com/image/photos/9800000/Great-Mountains-mountains-and-waterfalls-9842020-1920-1440.jpg");
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
}

#right {
float: left;
width: 33%;
height: 100vh;
-webkit-filter: contrast(3);
background-image: url("http://images2.fanpop.com/image/photos/9800000/Great-Mountains-mountains-and-waterfalls-9842020-1920-1440.jpg");
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
}

body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

Here's what it looks like at the end:

[image: Three divs with filters for backgrounds]

But I feel like there's a better way I could implement this.  Any suggestions on how this could be done in a better/more efficient way?

Comment: you can use Jquery for less and fast coding.

Comment: "you can use Jquery for less and fast coding."... Perhaps a demonstration?

Comment: For the next time, ask these kind of questions over at Code Review.

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks SZenc!  I'll be sure to submit over there next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your HTML is as effective as it is going to be. That said, your CSS could be made more compact by removing common properties and placing them in another CSS-tag. You would then get something like this

```
#left, #middle, #right {
  float:left;
  width:-webkit-calc(100% / 3);/*Makes the width exactly a third of the screen*/
  height:100vh;
  background-image: url("http://images2.fanpop.com/image/photos/9800000/Great-Mountains-mountains-and-waterfalls-9842020-1920-1440.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
#left {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
}
#middle {
  -webkit-filter: sepia(1);
}
#right {
  -webkit-filter: contrast(3);
}
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```